# list('\a','\b','\c') prints '\x07', '\x08', '\\c'

Tags: python

In python3.6, I tried

```
In [60]: a = '\a'
In [61]: b = '\b'
In [62]: c = '\c'
In [63]: l =[a, b, c]
```

If test `l`

```
In [64]: l
#it output following list instead of  ['a','\b','\c']
Out[64]: ['\x07', '\x08', '\\c']
```

encapsulate them directly in a list.

```
In [70]: ['\a','\b','\c']
#it output following list instead of  ['a','\b','\c']
Out[70]: ['\x07', '\x08', '\\c']
```

What's the mechanism behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is the escape character to allow you to enter non-printable characters into a string literal.

One of the most known escape sequences for example is `\n` for a newline.

`\a` is the [bell character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) and `\b` is the [backspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace) character.